# Yandex map ошибка net::ERR_ABORTED 429 (Too Many Requests)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем привет. Использую яндекс карты для отображения меток через геокодер и прорисовки маршрута от точки А до точки Б при помощи "routePanelControl". Сгенерировал ключ апи яндекса для "JavaScript API и HTTP Геокодер", скрипт карт подключаю с этим ключом. Сам геокодер работает нормально, рисует все необходимые точки, но построитель маршрута вообще не работает. Вместо этого появляется ошибка

`GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_156837181534799904393&text=195027%2C%20%D0%A0%D0%A4%2C%20%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%2C%20%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B4.%209%D0%90&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&results=1&token=c75c08aaa7168778b8dff36de0cd0201&type=geo&properties=addressdetails&geocoder_sco=latlong&origin=jsapi2Geocoder net::ERR_ABORTED 429 (Too Many Requests)`

Сразу подумал что привысил лимит подключений по api, но в ЛК разработчика яндекс в статистике вижу что лимит не исчерпан, хотя собственно проблем с геокодером нет, только маршрутизатор глючит.

Что делать, как быть, где копать?

Comment: Может дело не в count а в rate?

Comment: подробнее можно?

Comment: спустя пару часов простоя попробовал зайти на страницу и запустить скрипт и всё заработало. не знаю как это понимать. самое странное, что в статистике так и не отображается ни одного запроса, всё по нулям http://joxi.ru/D2PLjoqtqO0gB2

Comment: @AlMr если в статистике ничего нет и ловите 429, значит ключ прописан неверно и скоро всё совсем сломается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка 429 возникает только при использовании API без ключа. В вашем примере запроса его тоже нет. Это значит, что вы не прописали ключ в подключении API или прописали неверно, например, неправильно назван параметр, добавлены лишние символы и т.п.

Правильно ключ прописывается вот так:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=Absdf-adfa1-2131-241FFsf&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
```

Часто путают, например, регистр параметра `apikey` - все буквы должны быть маленькие, и берут ключ в скобки <> или случайно добавляют пробелы.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая проблема

Я отправлял запросы к геокодеру без API-ключа

Исправил следующим образом:

было

$.getJSON('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?',{

стало

$.getJSON('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=<мой ключ>',{