# Перестала работать яндекс карта сразу на нескольких сайтах

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть страница на тестовом поддомене http://solidauto.bestjob.by/contacts. На ней яндекс карта. Долгое время работала, а вчера перестала. 
В коде ничего не менялось. 
Есть несколько резервных на других поддоменах. Карта перестала работать сразу на всех. 
Ещё было такое. Утром дома включаю компьютер - карта работает. Перезагружаю - не работает. Пришёл на работу - ситуация аналогичная

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чём причина.

Comment: У нас аналогичная ситуация перестала работать яндекс карта. В консоль падают ошибки:
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_156882120078568808569&text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%20(%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0)&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&results=1&token=423e431618916355a7518883a7954e00&type=geo&properties=addressdetails&geocoder_sco=latlong&origin=jsapi2Geocoder net::ERR_ABORTED 429 (Too Many Requests) Доп.сервисы на которые ссылается новость https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/prekraschaem-podderzhku-anonimnykh-servisov (па

Comment: @АлексейRedsowet пропишите ключ и всё заработает.

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1024153/yandex-map-ошибка-neterr-aborted-429-too-many-requests/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Yandex map ошибка net::ERR\_ABORTED 429 (Too Many Requests)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1024153/yandex-map-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-neterr-aborted-429-too-many-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря техподдержке Яндекса проблема решена.
Я отправлял  запросы к геокодеру без API-ключа.

Исправил следующим образом:
было:

```
$.getJSON('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?',{
```

стало:

```
$.getJSON('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=<мой ключ>',{
```

Comment: Почему вы всё таки считаете, что этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1025832/217579) вам не помог?

Answer (score 1):

У вас там в консоли ошибки, в частности от API Карт ошибка 429. Она означает, что вы используете API без ключа. Без ключа API Карт не работает.

Пропишите ключ, как [описано в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/quick-start/index-docpage/?from=SO), и всё станет ОК.

```
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=myApiKey&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
```

Ключ надо получить в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/

Comment: Вы делаете запрос к геокодеру, чтобы получить координаты города и подставляете в карту. Геокодер отвечает 429, так как вы привысили лимит по ключу и как следствие карты получают пустые координаты.

Comment: Ключ подключался в модуле. Прописал ещё и в хедере сайта. Не помогло.
И как узнать про лимиты. Как решить вопрос с лимитами?

Comment: @ВалерийКурейчик Такие вопросы лучше задавать техподдержке, ошибка 429 не может возникнуть с ключом. Значит,  у вас как-то неправильно прописан ключ.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что API карт были подключены без использования API-ключа и яндекс отключил эту возможность.

Comment: Проверил на одном из старых проектов, работает без ключа.

Comment: Та же ситуация, прямо один-в-один. Ключ используется.

Comment: @PeterLozovitskiy без ключа API работать не будет, это анонсировалось [в Клубе](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/prekraschaem-podderzhku-anonimnykh-servisov?from=SO). Если ключ используется, но всё равно 429, значит, он прописан неверно - не в том параметре, с опечаткой, API подключен 2 раза на странице и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

От себя добавлю.

Если у вас к сайту подключена Яндекс Метрика - то может быть конфликт, если она расположена ниже скрипта карты. Решается просто - перенести скрипт метрики в head перед https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=[api-key]

Ну и главное ввести нужный API-ключ от js-api и геокодера, а не какой либо еще.

Answer (score 0):

была такая же проблема - писал в Техподдержку Яндекса - выяснил, есть конфликт ГИС API Ядекс Карт с mootools js библиотекой (у нас сайт на старом движке joomla, mootools отключить не получиться)

ТП посоветовало отключить compatibility для mootools (как и где это сделать я так и не понял)

// Но выяснилось что, подключая разные версии API можно добиться востановления отображение карты Яндекса + Не забываем подставить свой API разработчика

// API версии 2.0 с ошибками но Карта работает работает
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/

// API версии 2.1 ошибок в консоли нет и Карта не работает 
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/

Answer (score -1):

Я свою проблему решил. 
У меня был такой случай:

```
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=[api-key]
```

Поправил на вот такой и все заработало:

```
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=[api-key]
```

До исправления, в статистике были нули. Сейчас цифры появились. Видимо, сервис стал видеть API-ключ.

Comment: Оба варианта корректные, причина ошибки 429 точно не в этом.